# AWS DynamoDB and PhP - Forbidden Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Am using Amazon Elastic beanstalk and running a php server. Simple application program running fine however whenever am trying to connect to AWS DynamoDB, its giving me error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Below is the code

```
<?php
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
require 'config.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

$client = DynamoDbClient::factory($config);

$result = $client->describeTable(array(
    'TableName' => 'abcmsg'
));

echo 'Result is ', $result;

?>
```

Not sure if I need to set-up some IAM role but what and where those are reqd?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a **IAM instance profile**

### Follow the followign steps:

[image]

**Then select the role of your preference:**

[image]